# Parameter in route with Flask - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to handle parameters in the routing path in Flask:

```
@app.route('/example/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def tasks(id):

    if id == 1:
        obj = FirstTask()
    elif id == 2:
        obj = SecondTask()
    elif id == 3:
        obj = ThirdTask()

    result = obj.start()
    
    return make_response(jsonify({ 'data': { result } }), 200)
```

After run, I get following error:

"local variable 'obj' referenced before assignment"

I've never programmed in Python and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: When you called `obj.start()`, `obj` was not defined yet because none of your if statements evaluated True.  In other words, none of your `obj = Task()` statements were called.  Define `obj` before the if or in an else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bugs, working in concert:

1. You're comparing apples to oranges, that is strings to integers.
2. You don't handle invalid `id`s.

The solution for the first is to add a converter to the route (`int:`), the solution for the second is to add an `else`:

```
from flask import abort

@app.route('/example/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def tasks(id):

    if id == 1:
        obj = FirstTask()
    elif id == 2:
        obj = SecondTask()
    elif id == 3:
        obj = ThirdTask()
    else:
        abort(404)

    result = obj.start()
    
    return make_response(jsonify({ 'data': { result } }), 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because obj is not defined in your if statement logic.  Maybe add an `else` and check for None like this:

```
@app.route('/example/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def tasks(id):

    if id == 1:
        obj = FirstTask()
    elif id == 2:
        obj = SecondTask()
    elif id == 3:
        obj = ThirdTask()
    else:
        obj = None

    if obj is not None:
        result = obj.start()
    
        return make_response(jsonify({ 'data': { result } }), 200)
```